# Android, IOS and phonegap

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application on android and iphone, both of them created on eclipse-xcode.
Now Im rebuliding the application using angular.js + phonegap, but I have two questions.

1) when submitting my new app (phonegap) to market, can I submit it as an update for the old app (android-ios)? Or should I remove the old apps and upload the new app as a new application on the market?

2) is there any restrections on ios/android market for using phonegap?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google terms of service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your questions

> 1) when submitting my new app (phonegap) to market, can I submit it as
>   an update for the old app (android-ios)? Or should I remove the old
>   apps and upload the new app as a new application on the market?

Yes, you can. There is no such restriction or check from Google or Apple

> 2) is there any restrections on ios/android market for using phonegap?

No, totally not, there are no such restrictions either

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

1. As long as you use the same bundle id (e.g. com.company.app) and sign it with the same keystone file (Android) and provisioning profile (iOS) there will be no problem updating your app.
2. Sure not, I have many apps on Android and iOS created with phonegap and I never had any problem with publishing